There is some way to apply a custom mask to a FormKit field? I want to write a custom mask
how can I add a mask to the value of this field while the user is typing?
<FormKit
  type="text"
  name="postalcode"
  label="Postal Code"
  placeholder="Insert a postal code"
  validation="required|length:9|matches:/^\d{5}\-\d{3}$/"
/>

when the user inputs "123456", the value should be masked to "12345-6" until it reachs the maxlength of 9 characters
I've tried with @input event, but it always ends with a infinite recursive call

What is the function doing exactly? Should not be recursive.

I was trying to get the FormKitNode value, apply a mask by replacing the value and reseting the value using the input method from FormKit.
ex: @input="(_, node) => maskInput(node)"
and the maskInput looks like maskInput (node) { node.input(maskedValueComingFromSomewhere) }

You could probably fix it with some CSS?

how can I apply a mask to a field with CSS dude? Its like a validation to the data that my user is inserting in a field, CSS still cannot do it

On a validation condition apply a class (given a computed prop) and with the given class change the display of the text in the input with some selectors. Sounds totally feasible. This could even be possible with only HTML and CSS nowadays given the latest progress with the spec 4. No need for crazy JS manipulations here.

I think the question was not clear enough. The mask must be applied to the field, so that when performing a getNode('some_id').value query this return has the mask applied.

At the time this comment is being written, it is impossible to use CSS to solve the mentioned problem
